# How does vlc.py play video stream?

Tags: python, video-streaming, vlc

I want to use vlc.py to play mpeg2 stream http://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings.

There are some examples here: http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=examples;hb=HEAD

When I run the examples, it just can play video file, I want to know is there any examples to play video stream ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If so, consider posting an answer.

Comment: Well, VLC can open streaming video if you pass the URL of the video to it, so I guess the same thing must be done with the Python API.

Comment: @why Did you solve this issue ? Please consider posting an answer

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](http://pastebin.com/edncPpW0) Pastebin entry, linked to in [this](https://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc-devel/2012-September/090310.html) mailing list, it can be solved using a method like this:

```
import vlc
i = vlc.Instance('--verbose 2'.split())
p = i.media_player_new()
p.set_mrl('rtp://@224.1.1.1')
p.play()
```

I haven't tried it though, so please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bare bones solution:

```
import vlc
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new('http://localhost/postcard/GWPE.avi')
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

if the media is a local file you will have to alter:

```
Media = Instance.media_new('http://localhost/postcard/GWPE.avi')
Media.get_mrl()
```

to:

```
Media = Instance.media_new_path('/path/to_your/file/filename.avi')
```

note that you must lose the `get_mrl()` as well as changing the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
import vlc
vlcInstance = vlc.Instance()
player = vlcInstance.media_player_new()
player.set_mrl("rtsp://URL_PATH")
player.play()
```

I was able to open a stream with the following code, combining the previous answers.
Tested this with a network webcam