# How to get audiostream metadata using vlc.py

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc, python-vlc

for a little project I need to get the metadata(mainly title and artist) from songs on audio streams, for this I am using the vlc python library. This is my code with a Belgian radio station as an example:

```py
import vlc
def getData(url):
    Instance = vlc.Instance()
    player = Instance.media_player_new()
    Media = Instance.media_new(url)
    Media.get_mrl()
    player.set_media(Media)
    player.play()
    return player.audio_get_track_description()

print(getData("http://icecast.vrtcdn.be/mnm-high.mp3"))
```

But all I get is an empty array:
`[]`

I got a part of the code from another stackoverflow thread and am not entirely sure on how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34244909/14788941

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The media has to have been `parsed` before the meta information is available.
On these webcasts, it appears the only way to do this is `play` it and then the meta item to check is `NowPlaying`. The `Title` comes back with a generic string, something like `Title 1`.
To add to the misery, callback events registered on `vlc.EventType.MediaMetaChanged` don't seem to be activated.

A quick look as follows:

```
import vlc
import time

def getData(url):
    Instance = vlc.Instance()
    player = Instance.media_player_new()
    Media = Instance.media_new(url)
    Media.get_mrl()
    player.set_media(Media)
    player.play()
    prev = ""
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        m = Media.get_meta(12) # vlc.Meta 12: 'NowPlaying',
        if m != prev:
            print("Now playing", m)
            prev = m
    return player.audio_get_track_description()

print(getData("http://icecast.vrtcdn.be/mnm-high.mp3"))
```

Right now, this has given:

```
Now playing None
[00007fc830005ab0] prefetch stream error: unimplemented query (264) in control
Now playing JUSTIN BIEBER feat. LUDACRIS - BABY
Now playing LAUV & ANNE-MARIE - FUCK, I'M LONELY
Now playing MODJO - LADY (HEAR ME TONIGHT)
Now playing MILOW - AYO TECHNOLOGY
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, tnx!